# Laptop built-in screen stays dark, but backlight and external displays work

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, laptop-display

This morning my Sony Vaio laptop (core i7, Windows 8.1, Radeon graphics) from 2013 booted just fine (LED behavior, fan) and I observed backlight action on the built-in screen (it changed between different levels of "not-quite-black"). Alas, no graphics whatsoever were displayed (no BIOS messages, even after I removed and re-inserted the battery for a true cold-start, no "Windows boot wait-wheel", certainly no login screen or desktop).

When I attached a beamer through HDMI for which I has previously configured "duplicate desktop" I saw the usual desktop and could operate the computer, so it is working as expected, including the HDMI part of the graphics adapter.

From these symptoms I gather the following:

- Most of the hardware (mainboard, RAM, CPU, disk etc.) is working just fine.
- The display's backlight is working.
- The graphics adapter is at least partially working.

I'm probably going to open the computer today in order to look for a loose contact or broken cable. But I thought I'd ask here:

**Has anybody experienced a partial failure of the graphics adapter/chip (perhaps specifically a mobile Radeon) for just one of the outputs?**

Update: A look at the mainboard, cable, display and connectors didn't reveal any obvious defects. But I didn't dare disassemble the lid enough to fully inspect the display side of the cable connection; I was afraid to damage something. But I could peek at it and it looked OK afaics.

Comment: Most likely it's the inverter that has failed. I have replaced one before on a laptop.

Comment: @HelpingHand, that's a common cause, but in this case, the backlight is still working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is likely to be in the lid or the cable feeding it.  It could well be a problem with a ribbon cable or its connection.  But if you don't see something obvious, this kind of problem is hard to diagnose without swappable spare parts, a service manual, and equipment.

If you take it to the shop, they might try swapping some cables, but few shops do board-level repairs.  If a cable swap doesn't fix it, they will likely just replace pretty much everything in the lid.

A six-year-old laptop is at an age where other components are likely to start to fail.  If reseating or swapping a ribbon cable fixes it, the cost should be pretty reasonable.  But having a shop replace everything in the lid will cost a substantial fraction of the cost of a new laptop.  They will likely use refurbished parts and provide a 90 day warranty.

That's not a great investment.  You will still have an old laptop where other components, or even the repair, won't have a long expected life.  If you put that money toward a new laptop instead, you will have new and better technology, all new components, and a reasonable warranty.

BTW, if you like the fact that your laptop is pre-Windows 10, because you don't want to move to Win 10, you may be able to find old stock of previous-generation laptops that are still factory new and carry a full warranty.  In the US, retailers like Walmart and even Amazon buy up lots of residual inventory at huge discounts and then sell them at low prices.  So a replacement laptop doesn't necessarily need to be expensive, and the savings on not replacing the lid could go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

(May 2021)
Right click on desktop and select screen resolution.
Under 'multiple displays' select 'extend these displays' and click apply then accept changes.
Then go back to multiple displays and select your external monitor, click apply and accept changes.
Fixes the issue of back light being continuously on on the laptop screen when its not in use without the need for expensive repairs. (win8.1 May 2021)
Hope this helps someone